# How to prevent GDB from exiting when reaching execve?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, fork

Currently debugging a tcsh like remake, I used :

`set follow-fork-mode child`
to follow a child program after fork but reaching the execve system call GDB exit and I got the following message :

`process 11217 is executing new program: /usr/bin/cat
zsh: suspended (tty output)  gdb ./mysh`

How can I prevent that ?

Thanks  you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the child got suspended?

You can let the child run with:

```
set detach-on-fork on
```

This is the default. You can check with `show detach-on-fork` whether it's been turned off (perhaps via `.gdbinit`?).

To follow the exec'ed process, you can use:

```
set follow-exec-mode new
```

You can also switch between multiple processes using `inferior`. First get inferior numbers via:

```
info inferiors
```

Then to switch:

```
inferior <num>
```